# Elixir, default keyword list argument

Tags: promise, elixir, default-arguments, keyword-argument

In elixir is possible to use default arguments in function definitions, but I found it impossible to do so with single keyword list arguments like:

```
def do_stuff(
  success: sucess \\ fn(conn) -> conn end,
  error: error
) do
  # ...
end
```

Also, I thought about avoiding this kind of "callback passing" style of coding by using something like JS promises but I couldn't find an implementation of promises for Elixir.

Maybe there's something built in right into the language that could help me write better code and closer abide to the elixir standards.

**Main question:** is possible to use default keyword arguments?

**Side question:** Is there something Elixir provides to help avoid this "callback passing" style of programming in favor of a more reactive/composable mechanism?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use default keyword arguments as keyword arguments are just syntactic sugar over a single keyword list:

```
do_stuff(success: ..., failure: ...)
```

is the same as

```
do_stuff([success: ..., failure: ...])
```

So a keyword list is really just a single argument. What you're doing in your function definition is **matching** on the keyword list passed to `do_stuff/1`: be sure to watch out for this as well, because your function definition will not match if the order of the keywords is not the same (i.e., `do_stuff(failure: ..., success: ...)`).

I think a nice way to overcome this is simply use two different arguments for the `do_stuff` function:

```
def do_stuff(success \\ fn(conn) -> conn end, failure \\ fn(err) -> err end)
```

This way default arguments work as expected. If you really need your argument to be a keyword list, then you can handle defaults inside the body of the function:

```
def do_stuff(options) do
  success = options[:success] || (fn(conn) -> conn end)
  failure = options[:failure] || (fn(err) -> err end)
end
```

Finally, about the "callback style" you mentioned, I don't know about anything that works much differently than just passing `fn` for when something is done, unless you start looking into concurrency and message passing.